# Responding to a click event using JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to monitor the click of a button in my page, when it is clicked I need to fire a POST request. With this request I need to send some course ID to the PHP so that I can delete that course from the database. To achieve this, I did something like this;

I have a table with course details and a button as following,

```
<table>
<tr><td>Course ID</td>
<td>Course Name</td>
<td>Avail.  Quota</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>CS101</td>
<td>Programming 1</td>
<td> 2 <input style="margin-left: 320px;"  type="button" id="submit" value="Cancel" cid="CS101"/></td>
</tr><tr><td>CS315</td>
<td>Objects</td>
<td>5<input style="margin-left: 320px;"  type="button" id="submit" value="Cancel" cid="CS315"/></td>
</tr></table>
```

I have a row of course details and a button at the end to delete the course. I have a JQuery like this set up to handle click event;

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit').fadeOut(300);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'del_course.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'action': 'delete', 'cid': '11239528343'},
        success: function(data, status) {
            if(data == "ok") {
                // Change page to indicate that deletion was successful
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
)};
)};
```

At this stage, `del_course.php` is just redirecting to an empty page to see if click is detected. `del_course.php` is as follows;

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == "delete") {
    $cid = $_POST['cid'];             
    echo (''.$cid.' will be deleted.'); 
    echo "ok";
    header( 'Location: empty.php' );
}
?>
```

What am I missing here? Nothing happens when I click to that input element. Also, you can see that for this example, I am just hardcoding course ID as cid in AJAX script. How can I pass cid from the input element so that I will pass respective course ID for clicked buttons?

Comment: Use some debugging and check for error messages. With this error description, it could be anything from a server side credential issue to not binding an event to the button in the first place. Narrow it down, please.

Comment: Definitely need to change the usage of several elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding to two elements which have the same ID,  I suggest switching the buttons to classes and then using proper scoping through the 'this' object.

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(event){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).fadeOut(300);

$.ajax({
    url: 'del_course.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'action': 'delete', 'cid': '11239528343'},
    success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "ok") {
            // Change page to indicate that deletion was successful
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

and change the buttons to `<input style="margin-left: 320px;"  type="button" class="submit" value="Cancel" cid="CS101"/>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that those last:

```
)};
)};
```

Should be:

```
});
});
```

To track down your ajax response you can use `console.log` or something like this:

`del_course.php`

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == "delete") {
  $cid = $_POST['cid'];             
  echo (''.$cid.' will be deleted.');       
}
?>
```

`Ajax call`

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I handled those. I am quite new to all these and by the suggestion of the comment above by GolezTrol, I am trying to learn to use Chrome Developer Tools. But do you see anything wrong other than that? By the way, how can I see if the button is bound to an event or not?

Comment: With everyone's help, I am able to successfully bind correct event to the button. But PHP function returns empty string as data when I want to alert it, rather than "ok". Btw, I have changed it to return just "ok", before I was also returning cid as stated in the one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

for this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
    e.preventDefault();
```

You have two event values, I believe you want:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This should properly stop the `POST` so that you can do it asynchronously with your following AJAX call

Comment: I corrected this and other errors posted here but I can't still get it to work. I am trying to trace the call but debugging web apps is quite new to me.

Comment: This will likely not fix your issue, but you should not have two elements with the same id. An id is meant to be unique, you should instead make both inputs have class=submit, and call $('.submit').on

Comment: I am currently looking for the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(data == "ok") {
            // Change page to indicate that deletion was successful
}
```

The data will not be just

```
"ok"
```

Because of:

```
echo (''.$cid.' will be deleted.'); 
echo "ok";
```

See the issue?
simple, remove the first echo